# renderFile do not load custom Twig extensions

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to create my own Generator, using SensioGeneratorBundle as a core. But there is a problem with custom Twig extensions loading.
If I use

`return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('Acme:Generator/Work:edit.html.twig', array());`

extension is working, but if I use

```
return $this->renderFile('edit.html.twig', array('entity' => $entity));
```

where

```
protected function renderFile($template, $parameters)
{
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->skeletonDirs), array(
        'debug'            => true,
        'autoReload'       => true,
        'cache'            => false,
        'strict_variables' => true,
        'autoescape'       => true,
    ));

    return $twig->render($template, $parameters);
}
```

Only core Twig extensions are loaded. And I get an error

> The filter "price" does not exist in edit.html.twig at line 9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SensioGeneratorBundle` creates it's own Twig instance in `renderFile()` method you gave, and it doesn't have anything in common with Twig instance loaded into Symfony's service container, which is being used by calling `$this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse()`.

And you can't use Twig instance from service container here, because it has some behaviours which could break Sensio's skeleton rendering. So the new Twig Environment instance is created on purpose in `renderFile()` method.

You need to add filters manually to newly created Twig Environment instance in `renderFile()` method, as simple as:

```
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

About Twig filters:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters